# How to return after Facebook share on a our site and close the pop up?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I have a one site , there I want to place a Facebook share button after the sharing the url or link return back on the site and show the coupon instead of share button.

We are waiting for the answers.
If any one give the right answer or make the script  , I will give the some bouns.

Comment: FYI, I think it's against the Facebook TOS to incentivise people to like/share your product in this way.

Comment: no, we can make it by facebook app.

Comment: i am just asking, if you have any shortway to do this, please let me know/.

Answer (score 2):

From the Facebook official documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

I don't know specifically how to redirect to your site, however I suggest you to switch to like button in any case

Answer (score 2):

I'm no lawyer, but it appears that forcing a person to share something is not correct

https://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php

> You must not
>   condition registration or entry upon the user taking any action using
>   any Facebook features or functionality other than liking a Page,
>   checking in to a Place, or connecting to your app. For example, you
>   must not condition registration or entry upon the user liking a Wall
>   post, or commenting or uploading a photo on a Wall.

You should have your corporate attorney take a look at this before proceeding further with forcing a share.

Like is easy to do and is explicitly permissible.  See:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's sharer.php is no longer deprecated but I suggest you switch to using [dialog/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2) to steer folks back to your coupon.

```
<a id='fb-share' style='text-decoration:none;' type='icon_link' onClick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?display=popup&app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&link=THE_PAGE_WITH_THE_SHARE_BUTTON?&description=MY_AWESOMENESS&redirect_uri=THE_PAGE_WITH_THE_COUPON&picture=URL_OF_A_PRETTY_IMAGE', 'mywindow', 'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=580,height=325');
return false;" href="javascript: void(0)">Share on Facebook</a>";
```

I can not find a TOS violation for offering coupons to those that like or share.